# How add from Jenkins UI Post step to run only if Build succeeds and what is option to run only on weekdays

Tags: jenkins

I looked online. Didn't find info. My some Jenkins jobs in UI have a Post Build option to Run only if build succeeds. I want to add it to all other jobs. I am not finding where to add it from in UI.